# dependency Issue, what is this error telling exactely

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I updated my react and react router-dom to the latest version, however now it is creating a lot of issues. I am not sure if that's because other packages aren't compatible with the newest version or what's not

```
$ npm i node-fetch@latest
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-notify-toast@0.5.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0-rc.1 || ^18.0.0" from @react-aria/ssr@3.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-aria/ssr
npm ERR!     @react-aria/ssr@"^3.2.0" from @restart/ui@1.4.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@restart/ui
npm ERR!       @restart/ui@"^1.4.1" from react-bootstrap@2.7.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!         react-bootstrap@"^2.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @restart/hooks@0.4.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/hooks
npm ERR!     @restart/hooks@"^0.4.7" from @restart/ui@1.4.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@restart/ui
npm ERR!       @restart/ui@"^1.4.1" from react-bootstrap@2.7.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!         react-bootstrap@"^2.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     @restart/hooks@"^0.4.6" from react-bootstrap@2.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^2.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   18 more (@restart/ui, react-bootstrap, react-dom, react-icons, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-notify-toast@0.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-notify-toast
npm ERR!   react-notify-toast@"^0.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-notify-toast@0.5.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-notify-toast
npm ERR!     react-notify-toast@"^0.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: you have to choose npm install --force or npm install --legacy-peer-deps I suggest second for stability.

Answer (score 0):

delete the node_modules folder to ensure a clean install and use this command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```